# What is wrong with my setup.py to install all dependencies in python 3.8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below setup.py script. When I execute the command `setup.py install`, I do not see the python packages installed in my system. In case of java, we use maven or gradle so that it can automatically download and install in the system. I want exact feature in setup.py. I see that **colorama**, **configparser** are not installed, I manually installed setuptools and cx-Freeze using pip command. Below is my **setup.py** script contents.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Command

setup(
    name="Runner",  # program name
    version="0.0.1",
    description='A utility to build an exe',
    author="Debadatta Mishra",
    author_email="deba.java@gmail.com",
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=['configparser==4.0.2', 'colorama==0.4.3', 'setuptools==45.2.0', 'cx-Freeze==6.1']
)
```

If I execute `pip list`, I do not see colorama, configparser etc. Please help me , I am new to python programming.

To run the setup script, I use the command `python setup.py install` in command prompt.

Comment: What is the ouput of the `python setup.py install` command ?

Comment: It runs without error but packages are not installed.

Comment: What is the output of `pip -V` ?

Comment: It is latest one ie. 20

Comment: I don't know if it will matter, but instead of running `python setup.py install`, run `pip install .` and let pip handle the installation; it does things a little differently from the plain `setup.py install` which is an older way of installing packages.

Comment: @Iguananaut, I agree, but if I give this project to some other developer, he has to manually install all the packages using `pip install` command. Think like maven or gradle type for java, package.json for node.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "manually install all the packages".  If you run `pip install .` in the directory your `setup.py` resides in, it will process all the dependencies from `install_requires` as well.  This is the "correct" way to install Python packages these days, as pip is ostensibly independent of setuptools and the different ways it does things.

Comment: @Iguananaut, I tried as per your suggestion by using the command `pip install .`, I am getting the error `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:`

Comment: @Iguananaut, but I thank you that there is a direct command to install, I learnt from you. However it is not working in my system, do I have to update anything ? I am using latest Python 3.8, Pip 20 version.

Comment: What is the rest of the error message?  It sounds from your question (and from the answers since no one can reproduce the problem) that you do in fact have one or more problems with your environment.

Comment: Please remove the "'setuptools==45.2.0'" from your `install_requires`--unless `setuptools` itself is somehow a runtime dependency of your package, it shouldn't be in this list.

Comment: Mam, I removed, still the same error.

Comment: After much struggle, it worked with this command `pip install -e .`. Thanks a lot @Iguananaut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Iguananaut, if you have a setup.py and if it has install_requires with the mentioned python packages. You can use the below command in windows to install the python packages.

```
pip install -e .
```

As mentioned above .(dot) is required.

Comment: To be clear, this is true on any platform.  I didn't say this in the comments, but might I also suggest instead of just `pip` to run `python -m pip` instead, where you can replace the "python" with the path/filename of the *specific* Python interpreter for which you want to install a package.  A mistake many beginners make is they have multiple Python interpreters on their system, but the main `pip` executable is not associated with the Python they are trying to use, so they install packages for the wrong python.  `python -m pip` ensures you're using the right pip for the right Python.

Comment: Thank you Mam for this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your *setup.py*. There must be something wrong with your environment, because when your script is running in clean docker environment is works.

Create clean environment by using such a Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.1-buster
RUN mkdir /debmis
ADD setup.py /debmis
WORKDIR /debmis
RUN python setup.py install
CMD /usr/bin/env pip list
```

Build it (having your setup.py in current directory):

```
docker build -t python3 .
```

And run

```
docker run python3

Package      Version
------------ -------
colorama     0.4.3  
configparser 4.0.2  
cx-Freeze    6.1    
pip          20.0.2 
Runner       0.0.1  
setuptools   45.1.0 
wheel        0.34.2
```

I suggest comparing difference between `python setup.py install` executed in your environment and executed by `docker build`.

Comment: I am using simply in windows 10 not in dockerized container. even I do not want docker for a simple python project.

Comment: Sure, I suggested docker as cross-check tool only. To check whether the problem is in setup.py or whether it is outside. It is outside.